# When trying to open the html file via a browser, it cannot find the /img or /js folder

Tags: javascript, html, path

[image: Project path]
[image: js path reference]
[image: imgs path reference]

It works when I launch the page on the ide built in browser, but not when I open it directly from my files. Am I doing something wrong with how I have the paths setup? Im new to working with css and javascript, if its something simple I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the leading slash within the src attribute of your img tag to load images from a folder that is on the same level of the folder hierarchy as your HTML file.
It has to look like this:

```html
<img src="images/thinking.jpg" ...></img>
```

Comment: Thank you i feel like i wasted your time with such a dumb type on my part.